# how to protect a route from being used until after they verified?

Tags: node.js

Assume the user wants to go to their settings page where they could change their personal info (e.g. first name). I want to trigger an OTP sent to their phone to verify it is actually the user going to this page before they could actually update their info. We use a third party service that handles the sms part (expiration, error message etc). I have the whole sending + updating part figured out, I'm just unsure on how to protect the update route only after they're verified.

Does anyone know what the best practice with this use case? i would be grateful for any help.

```
/* verifies if the access token (which user gets upon login) is valid */
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('access-token');
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json('Not Authorized');

  try {
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secret');
    req.userId = payload.userId
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).json('Invalid.');
  }
};


/* sends one time password to user */
router.post(
  '/update/user-check/send',
  auth,
  async (req, res) => {
    try {

      // gets user from db
      const curUser = await getUser({
        userId: req.userId,
      });

      // sends otp
      await SMSService.sendOneTimePasswordThroughPhone(curUser.phoneNumber)

      res.status(200).json("sent one time password")

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return res.status(401).json(e);
    }
  },
);

/* verifies one time password to user */
router.post(
  '/update/user-check/verify',
  auth,
  async (req, res) => {
    try {

      const oneTimePassword = req.body.oneTimePassword

      // gets user from db
      const curUser = await getUser({
        userId: req.userId,
      });

      // checks otp
      const result = await SMSService.checkOTP(oneTimePassword, curUser.phoneNumber);
      res.status(200).json("verified")

    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(401).json(e);
    }
  },
);


/* updates user's first name */
router.put(
  '/update/first-name',
  auth,
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // updates first name
      const curUser = await updateFirstName({
        userId: req.userId,
      });
      res.status(200).json("updated first name")
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(401).json(e);
    }
  },
);
```

There is one big flaw with my implementation. I have no way to ensure '/update/first-name' route is protected only after they are validated. How do I go about this ? For example, currently if they use the put route and they haven't verified otp yet, then it would still allow them to use that route

Comment: Is this a one time thing or are they supposed to do this often? Can you store it somehow in the frontend the session key and then send it in a header?

Comment: For now, everytime. Are you suggesting I create a new jwt on top of the existing access token for this purpose ?

Comment: That could be one possible way I think, then it could expire as well.

Comment: That is something I already considered. However, I think it may be overkill? The third party service we're using already tells us whether the otp is expired, valid, invalid, etc.

Comment: What if you do it in a different order then and skip the verify route totally, so that when a user updates their information, you request the OTP code, and then when the user fills it in you both check the code and if it's correct proceed with the rest of the put request? A general suggestion would also be to not have different routes for everything that the user wants to update, for example send an object with what they're changing and modify those:

Comment: So I think what you mean is update route will also have the verify thing on it? That wont work. What if the user wants to update their first name twice ? The first code would have already expired after being used. Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247755/discussion-between-anonymous-user-and-user349557).